# How to use ListDeserializer properly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

A Kafka listener container factory should be configured to consume messages whose values are a list of objects. I tried to configure the factory using [`ListDeserializer`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ListDeserializer.html) in the following way:

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
  @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
  private String bootstrapServers;

  @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
  private String groupId;

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<Item>>
      kafkaListenerContainerFactoryItem() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<Item>> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(
        new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            props,
            new StringDeserializer(),
            new ListDeserializer<>(ArrayList.class, new JsonDeserializer<>(Item.class, false))));
    return factory;
  }
}
```

But the exception below appears:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: List deserializer was already initialized using a non-default constructor 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ListDeserializer.configure(ListDeserializer.java:78) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.lambda$valueDeserializerSupplier$9(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:483) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:451) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:427) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:394) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:371) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:776) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:352) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:461) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:209) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:461) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:347) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:292) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

How can the container factory be properly configured using `ListDeserializer`?

Comment: Doing `new ListDeserializer<>(ArrayList.class, new JsonDeserializer<>(Item.class, false), false)` *will* work around that exception/line, but regarding "(side)effects": not sure, please test/see ... (there is a overloaded consturctor with `boolean configureDeserializers` parameter...https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java)

Comment: "`@param configureDeserializers false to not configure the deserializers`"

Comment: @xerx593 It works and I haven't encountered any side effects yet. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Since</del> If we <del>don't</del> wouldn't use any relevant (deserializer) config, the quickest fix would be to use:

```java
// ...
new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
  props,
  new StringDeserializer(),
  new ListDeserializer<>(
    ArrayList.class, new JsonDeserializer<>(Item.class, false)
  ),
  false /* !!! */
)//...
```

Where `false` refers to `configureDesirializers` parameter of (an overloaded) constuctor. ([ref](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java))

<del>In this case it has no side/negative effects, since you:</del>

- Use `StringDeserializer` as key deserializer.

  It has the only "configuration option": `[[key|value].]deserializer.encoding` (which we don't set and which defaults to `UTF-8`). ([ref](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringDeserializer.java))
- <del>For the value desirializer (a `ListDeserializer`), you "configure" already everything usefull (via constructor parameters).</del> ([ref](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ListDeserializer.java))

We do:

```java
props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
```

.../want to configure our `JsonDeserializer`, then the "workaround" breaks this setting!

We should configure `props`, and initialize the factory with empty (deserializer) constructors:

```java
// props.put(...);
// when this is *really* needed (otherwise, quickfix!):
props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
// extra config for our "value deserializer" (analogous to constructor):
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.DEFAULT_LIST_VALUE_SERDE_TYPE_CLASS, ArrayList.class /*alternatively: "java.util.ArrayList" (string!) */);
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.DEFAULT_LIST_VALUE_SERDE_INNER_CLASS,
 /* this looks little hacky, i am open to better proposals (we need Serde here): */
 Serdes.serdeFrom(
   new SomeItemSerializer(), /* <- we'll need this (not null!) due to api, but it can be "no-op" (is never used with given code) */
   new JsonDeserializer<>(Item.class, false)
 )
);
// and then:
// ...
factory.setConsumerFactory(
  new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
    props,
    new StringDeserializer(),
    new ListDeserializer<>(/* just empty */)
    /* now with configureDeserializers = true/default */
  )
); // ...
```

To work around the (ugly) no-op-serializer, we could (try):

```
new Serdes.WrapperSerde(/*!!*/null, new JsonDeserializer<>(Item.class, false))
```

..instead of:

```
Serdes.serdeFrom(..)
```

..and cross thumbs, that no-one/thing calls anything besides `deserializer()` on `WrapperSerde` (..otherwise: NPE! ..consumer does not serialize!;). ([ref](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serdes.java))

Comment: hmm, how about `JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*"` ?

Comment: ... this would not be propagated to JsonDeserializer with the "quick fix"!

Comment: True, but in my particular case I use `new JsonDeserializer<>(Item.class, false)` where `false` corresponds to the `useHeadersIfPresent` attribute which makes `JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES` redundant if I'm not mistaken, because it doesn't even look for a type header and therefore doesn't check trusted packages.